# Restful forums/groups/friends/tags etc from joomla

Tags: web-services, rest, content-management-system, joomla, restful-url

Are there any solutions that my app could consume forums/friends/groups etc features using joomla through RESTful urls.

I found 2 links so far,

1. Plexicloud-JWS :- This seems to supports only core features and not what Am looking out for
2. https://github.com/techjoomla/Joomla-REST-API 
   This seems to support jomsocial which looks a paid one

If I am not wrong, joomla and jomsocial seem different, is that kind of social wrapper over joomla?

If such solutions are not available with joomla, then with any other open source GPL/MIT in php/rails/java..?

Could any body provide me any pointers please?

thanks
Amol